# Insertion into a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

This is the code I came up with to insert a new value into a BST:

```
class BST(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = Node(root)

    def insert(self, new_val):
        self.__internal_insert(self.root, new_val)

    def __internal_insert(self, node, new_val):
        if node is None:
            node = Node(new_val)
        elif new_val < node.value:
            self.__internal_insert(node.left, new_val)
        else:
            self.__internal_insert(node.right, new_val)

# Set up the tree
tree = BST(4)

# Insert elements
tree.insert(2)
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(5)
```

however, while debugging I noticed that the `self.root` is never updated, eg.: as soon as the `__internal_insert()` method finishes and a new `insert()` is performed, its sibling nodes `left` and `right` are back to `None` instead to the previous value that was set.

Hope you help me spot where the bug is. I picked up Python recently, my apologizes if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `node = Node(new_val)`, but then where do you ever attach that node to it's parent?

Basically, you recurse, but never captured the results you're building

Try returning the node you created

```
def __internal_insert(self, node, new_val):
    if node is None:
        node = Node(new_val)
    elif new_val < node.value:
        node.left = self.__internal_insert(node.left, new_val)
    else:
        node.right = self.__internal_insert(node.right, new_val)
    return node
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues with the code.

First, when you reassign `node`, it is not assigning the value to the `BST` object. To do that, you need to reference it directly: `self.left = Node(new_val)`.

Second, you're not checking the equals condition, so your code isn't going to work like a traditional BST. You'll end up with a lot of extraneous nodes.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the second issue.